# Azure AD - SAML with 3rd party as IDP

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, saml, azure-ad-b2c

My current setup is .net web application plus Azure AD as IDP for my application. My application is a public web application where anyone can sign up and get in. We are in process of signing up a contract with one of our clients who already have their website and IDP (non-Microsoft).

Our requirement is that users login to their website, lets call it www.client.com and my website as www.mysite.com. So user "A" logs into www.client.com. User "A" sees a button "Go to mysite.com" on www.client.com. Once "A" click on this button, if he exists on mysite.com, he sees dashboard directly but if "A" does not exist - he sees mysite.com signup page.

Question: Is it possible to have SAML based trust relationship between their non-microsoft IDP and my Azure AD which acts as service provider? if yes, how is it implemented so users dont see login page and auto-login to mysite.com if exists.

Comment: Have a look at https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-active-directory-identity/azure-ad-b2b-collaboration-direct-federation-with-saml-and-ws/ba-p/735133 . I'm not sure what type of app you've developed here (single tenant vs multi-tenant) and whether you are using Azure AD B2C or not. But B2B invites appear to be what you need.

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look. My app is single tenant - Azure AD B2C.

Comment: in that case review something like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-adfs2016-custom?tabs=applications . You may have to adopt instructions based on IDP in use at your customer

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You can use your Azure AD as a service provider for their IDP.

You need to set up Direct Federation with your client.

To set up Direct Federation and configure your Azure AD as a SP as per the [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/direct-federation).

Comment: Thanks. Would I be able to do this without requiring user invites? or if I can generate the invites programmatically?